# How to use previously created document id in same network call in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Okay, so here's what I want to achieve. First I will create a document in `fruits` collection,

```
{
  name: 'Apple'
}
```

Then, after getting the `_id` from created document, I want to create another document in `users` collection,

```
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  'favourite-fruit': ObjectId(123) // apple's id
}
```

But, how do I achieve this in single network call? I can use `then` in nodejs. I do not want to use that since it's costly. Is there any other way available?

Comment: I think there is missing information here about the context/constraints. What do you know and at what time? How are you searching the `fruits` collection, by the `name` field? Are you always guaranteed to find at least one document? What if more match? What if no matches are found? When you go to create the second document, do you have the `name` (and/or) other fields? Will you always create a new document, or could one already exist? If you can find more or fewer than 1 result in `fruits`, what do you want to do with the `users` document(s)?

Comment: @user20042973, both of the document will be created, also it does not matter if the first exists. I am not searching in `fruits` collection. I want to get the `id` that I just created and use it in another document. Since, creating first document and then getting the id of it and then create another document requires two network request, I want to know if there is any other way available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible the way you want it, but to me creating 2 documents in 2 calls does not look very inefficient Unless you create thousands?

Anyways, you can create the ID yourself that way you can use it right away.

```
const apple = {
  _id:ObjectId()
  name: 'Apple'
};
const user = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  'favourite-fruit':apple._id
};
```

In this, you do not let the driver or the mongo server set the ID, you set it yourself. By using the connector's ObjectId function you ensure that your ID will be formed like any other default ID.